# Why do files need time to synchronize after writing in writeType THROUGH in Alluxio?

Tags: alluxio

When I write file in directory mounted by alluxio-fuse using writeType THROUGH. I find that it takes 2-3 minutes to synchronize files. Why do files need time to synchronize?

Following is mount direactory. write time : 15:40.   after sync: 15:43

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing to Alluxio with THROUGH writeType, Alluxio will first update its metadata to show files with zero bytes (like the 9.txt in your first image). When the file is successfully written to Alluxio Under FileSystem, Alluxio will update its metadata to show the actual size of this file (9.txt show its actual size as 209715200 bytes).

The 2 to 3 minutes is the time that Alluxio writes data to under filesystem.

Thanks,